# Cannot open source file "ui_QtGuiApplication.h" in default Qt project

Tags: c++, qt

I installed the latest QT version and the QT tool for Visual Studio. When creating a new GUI project in Qt, the default program should create an empty window, but it seems that I'm getting an E1696 error in Visual Studio Community: "cannot open source file "ui_QtGuiApplication4.h".

The error takes place in the default header class created for the project:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_QtGuiApplication4.h"

class QtGuiApplication4 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtGuiApplication4(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::QtGuiApplication4Class ui;
};
```

The Ui tag is also not recognized.

I added the additional include directiories for the QT path and I tried switching up between the 64bit and 32bit version of QT, but I'm getting the same error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ui_<YourClass>.h` header file is a file that only gets generated for you when you compile your project. Qt's [User Interface Compiler `uic`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) will read your `.ui` file(s) and create the corresponding `ui_` headers before the actual C++ compiler is invoked.

So you have to give it at least one compile run to generate the file. Then your IDE should be smart enough to find it.

FYI: Using QtCreator 4.12 you won't even have to compile. The clang backend process will generate the file in a temp folder somewhere probably to give you the proper code inspections (regarding code completion and so on). As I read from your question you're using Visual Studio which doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Didn't work from the first few tries, but after repeatedly compiling, Visual Studio decided that it can suddenly manage all its dependencies. :) Works fine now, thanks!